# Graph API to change another users password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

1-  We created a webpart to change user’s password using app services / graph api  (/users/username   {passwordProfile:{“password”:”xxxx”})

2-  Because Directory.AccessAsUser.All is a delegated permission we need to add the user to the right role in order to get the access to change the password.

3-  We tried adding the user to different roles and none of them worked but global admin. We always got insufficient privileges to complete the operation”

Is there a way to do this with less privilege then Global Admin?

Comment: Please let us know if one of the below answers was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_a4bJiq4VJF2blC5&Q_CHL=gl
>

Answer (score 2):

Password changing is one of those privileged roles that cannot be just given in application api permissions.
2. that is correct. The Directory.AccessAsUser.All permissions is delegated only which means only users with the correct role can perform the functionality. See below for roles that can change passwords.

3. You should be able to change the passwords using the application only without delgated permissions for graph. you can if you assign the service principal of the app (app registration) to the Password Administrator role in azure ad. if you manage any other properties, you may be better off giving it Helpdesk administrator Role. same applies for the delegated user, if you put them in one of those 2 roles they should have access to change the passwords.

Comment: Steps to do this, explained here - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-reset-or-update-user-passwords-with-microsoft-graph-api-in-azure-ad-c6733c3b0ac3

Comment: This answer is very unrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give a role other than Global Admin role you can try with the [Privileged authentication administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#privileged-authentication-administrator) which can also help you modify the password for other users.

[image]

Make sure you have the Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission as well with the role to modify passwordProfile property.

Comment: Hi @Morio, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions :)-